# Differences of two ways of reading file

Tags: python, line

Just curious, is there any difference between the two ways below for file reading? Eso. in terms of memory usage.

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>

f=open(...)
  for line in f:
      #process line
```

Also I know for gzip file, the first one with 'with' cannot work.
thx

Comment: you must not indent the second case. The second case is not complete without `f.close()` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're quite identical, except that the first one makes sure the file is closed. The second does not. In other words, within the body of the `with` statement, `f` is just a file object which is exactly equivalent to the `f` object you get after just calling `open` in the second code snippet.

As you might know (and if you do not, make sure to read [the informative doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)), the `with` statement accepts an object that implements the context manager interface and invokes the `__enter__` method of the object on entry, and its `__exit__` method when it's done (whether naturally, or with an exception.

Looking at the source code (`Objects/fileobject.c`), here's the mapping (part of the `file_methods` structure) for these special methods:

```
{"__enter__", (PyCFunction)file_self,     METH_NOARGS,  enter_doc},
{"__exit__",  (PyCFunction)file_exit,     METH_VARARGS, exit_doc},
```

So, the file object's `__enter__` method just returns the file object itself:

```
static PyObject *
file_self(PyFileObject *f)
{
    if (f->f_fp == NULL)
        return err_closed();
    Py_INCREF(f);
    return (PyObject *)f;
}
```

While its `__exit__` method closes the file:

```
static PyObject *
file_exit(PyObject *f, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *ret = PyObject_CallMethod(f, "close", NULL);
    if (!ret)
        /* If error occurred, pass through */
        return NULL;
    Py_DECREF(ret);
    /* We cannot return the result of close since a true
     * value will be interpreted as "yes, swallow the
     * exception if one was raised inside the with block". */
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the possibly unnecessary but very informative dive into the interpreter :)